# JavaScript not working: "Function expected"

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the JavaScript in this page not working?
Code:
`

```
<!-- head -->
<head>

    <!-- title -->
    <title></title>

    <!-- title -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- fonts: sans-serif -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- fonts: serif -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href='css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- ======================================== -->
    <!-- Page specific Javascript -->

    <!-- script to change header content -->
    <script>
    </script>

</head>
<!-- /head -->


<!-- body -->
<body>

    <!-- .container -->
    <div class="container">

        <h1 id="heading" onmouseover="change" onmouseout="changeBack">Original heading</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Page specific Javascript -->
    <!-- script to change header content -->
    <script>
            function change() {
                var heading = document.getElementById('heading');
                heading.innerHTML("Changed heading");
            }

            function changeBack() {
                var heading = document.getElementById('heading');
                heading.innerHTML("Original heading");
            }
    </script>


</body>
<!-- /body -->
```

`

Nothing happens when I hover over the `<h1>`.
In Internet Explorer 11's developer tools there are 2 errors stating functions are expected on lines 67 & 72.

Comment: Well it would help if you called the functions by adding `()` to them. And you should not be using inline events.

Comment: `onmouseover="change"` => `onmouseover="change()"` and etc.

Comment: @epascarello No. It doesn't help.

Comment: innerHTML is not a function. Should be heading.innerHTML = 'foo'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should have `()` after the methods in the inline events as I mentioned in the comments.

But the issue is the fact `innerHTML` is not a method

```
heading.innerHTML("Changed heading")
```

should be

```
heading.innerHTML = "Changed heading";
```

[Reference: MDN innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Thanks! I am a newbie learning JavaScript This has been driving me mad for a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put parenthesis if you want the functions to be called.

```
onmouseover="change()" onmouseout="changeBack()"
```